# Check errors for ionic app when using android devices

Tags: cordova, testing, ionic-framework

i wonder if it is possible to monitor errors, console.logs when running ionic app on android devices,
using

```
ionic cordova run android -c or -l
```

will cause CORs issues, and i cant test the app if api requests will not work..
so, any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Running the app through either Xcode or Android Studio will enable you to monitor the app outputs.